# DateComponents doesn't seem to honor year

Tags: ios, swift, macos, foundation, nsdatecomponents

I'm attempting to convert a `Date` to a `DateComponents`, change a few properties, and get a new `Date` back. I've written the following code:

```
import Foundation
var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: .current, from: Date())
components.day = 7
components.month = 3
components.year = 1900
DateFormatter.localizedString(from: components.date!, dateStyle: .long, timeStyle: .long)
```

I've tested this in the `America/Denver` time zone/locale on an iOS Simulator on iOS 15.0 as well as a Swift REPL on my Mac running the latest macOS Big Sur and Xcode 13.0, and in both places, I get approximately the following output at the time of this writing:

```
March 7, 2021 at 9:38:13 AM MST
```

Everything about this is as expected, except for the year. I had explicitly set the year to be `1900`, but the year in the output is `2021`. How can I make `DateComponents` honor the year when generating a date, or how can I do this same kind of thing manually so it'll actually work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get **all** components from a date with `dateComponents(in:from:)`, you have to set also `yearForWeekOfYear` accordingly

```
components.yearForWeekOfYear = 1900
```

Or specify only the date and time components including `calendar` and `timeZone` you really need for example

```
var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.calendar, .timeZone, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date())
components.day = 7
components.month = 3
components.year = 1900
DateFormatter.localizedString(from: components.date!, dateStyle: .long, timeStyle: .long)
```

Comment: My ultimate end goal here is that I have 2 `UIDatePickers`. One where it sets both a date and a time, and the other where it just sets the time. I want the one that just sets the time to have its `date` be on the same calendar day as the first one, which selects both the date and time. I've been trying to keep those in sync manually, but I'm not sure if there's a better way to do that. This answer appears to work, though, so I'm accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Good catch (voted).  I did not realize that if you try to create a Date from all of the values in  DateComponents you had to set both `year` and `yearForWeekOfYear`.

Comment: @DuncanC As Sweeper pointed out you can set `yearForWeekOfYear` also to `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are getting *all* the date components, including `weekOfYear`, `weekOfMonth`, `dayOfWeek`, and most importantly, `yearForWeekOfYear`. When you set the date components to 1900-03-07, you did not set all those components correctly either, and when resolving a `Date` from a `DateComponents` that has such conflicting components, the algorithm just so happens to prefer the year they got from `yearForWeekOfYear`.

If you set those fields to `nil`, you will get the expected result:

```
var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: .current, from: Date())
components.day = 7
components.month = 3
components.year = 1900

components.yearForWeekOfYear = nil
```

There will still be conflicts in the date components though, and although this doesn't cause a crash, I'm not sure if this behaviour will change in the future. I suggest that you get *just* the components you need. For example:

```
var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([
    .calendar, .timeZone, .era, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second, .nanosecond
], from: Date())
```